# Make picture box locked in corner?

Tags: c#, winforms, padding, picturebox

How can I make my picture box always locked in the top-right corner of my winforms application, even if I resize the form window?

I tried to do this:

```
pictureBox1.Margin = new Padding(5,5,0,0);
```

But it didn't work.
I want it to be padding 5 from top and 5 from right, always. No matter what the size of the form window is.

Answer (score 5):

Set the Anchor property to Top,Right.

Answer (score 0):

just move the control to its position and set

Dock = None

Anchor = Top & Right